# SSL-REST-server with grizzly, ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: java, rest, https, jersey, grizzly

Im trying to accomplish a secure REST-server with grizzly using SSL. I configure my ressources in

```
package SPSServer.controller.Grizzly;
@Path("/")
public class MessageRessource {

@GET
@Path("serverinfo")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.TEXT_XML})
public ServerInfo serverinfo() {
    ServerInfo info = new ServerInfo();
    info.server = System.getProperty("os.name") + " " + System.getProperty("os.version");
    return info;
}



@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.TEXT_XML})
//@Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
public String message() {
    return "Yea! ";
}
}
```

Now im starting grizzly with

```
    webServer = new GrizzlyWebServer(1337, ".", true);
    SSLConfig sslConfig = new SSLConfig(true);
    webServer.setSSLConfig(sslConfig);
    ServletAdapter adapter = new ServletAdapter();
    final Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    adapter.addInitParameter(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES,    "SPSServer.controller.Grizzly.MessageRessource");
           adapter.addInitParameter(ClasspathResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CLASSPATH, ".");

    adapter.setContextPath("/");
    adapter.setServletInstance(new ServletContainer());

     webServer.addGrizzlyAdapter(adapter, new String[]{"/"});
     webserver.start();
```

`

It start with

> Mar 31, 2013 4:55:14 PM com.sun.grizzly.Controller logVersion
>   INFO: GRIZZLY0001: Starting Grizzly Framework 1.9.56 - 3/31/13 4:55 PM
>   Hit return to stop...

But when i try to access the ressource / 
`'(https://locahost:1337/)'` it throws me this error:

> Mar 31, 2013 4:56:12 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
>   INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
>     SPSServer.controller.Grizzly.MessageRessource
>   Mar 31, 2013 4:56:12 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
>   INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17.1 02/28/2013 03:28 PM'
>   Mar 31, 2013 4:56:13 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules 
>   SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
>   Mar 31, 2013 4:56:13 PM com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter doService
>   SEVERE: service exception:
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

I have tried getting grizzly to work (with the jersey HttpServerFactory i get an working rest-server without ssl, and i managed to get an httpsServer working but both combined got me an headache for days now) so now i really depend on your help.
Thanks in advance 
(I take no offence if someone corrects my grammar, i still have to learn it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this Jersey sample?

https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/com/sun/jersey/samples/https-clientserver-grizzly/1.17.1/https-clientserver-grizzly-1.17.1-project.zip

Comment: This is an older version. See for the up-to-date versions: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/